# Laravel eager loading with where() from its relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables that have relations

Budgets Table :

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| purpose | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| delivery_plan | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| status | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

Periods table :

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| term_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

Terms table :

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | tinyint(4) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| status | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

Budget Model :

```
public function period()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Period::class, 'delivery_plan', 'name');
}
```

Period Model :

```
public function budgets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Budget::class, 'delivery_plan', 'name');
}

public function term()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Term::class);
}
```

Term Model :

```
public function periods()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Period::class);
}
```

So each budget belongsTo one period, and period belongs to one term.
Then i'd like to query Budgets based on term's name.
So how to query it with laravel eager loading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use whereHas method :

```
$builder->whereHas('relationName', function (Builder $builder){ /* your query */ });
```

if you don't have any condition to apply, you can just use whereHas without the callback

you can chain multiple whereHas if you need to

```
Budget::whereHas("period", function(Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('term', function(Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('name', '=', 'test');
            })
        })
```

you can even simplify that by using dot notation

```
Budget::whereHas("period.term", function(Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('name', '=', 'test');
        })
```

Comment: I tried the shortest by using dot notation, and boom this is what i wanted. Thanks a lot @Lk77 !

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). So, you can link between the `Budget` and `Term` via `Period`