# How to use Where clause on laravel relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

For each of the data in Post table , I have to check whether the field `name` of the relation `user` has value equal to `$request->name` and output the posts matching this condition . But The below code (Method 1) returns null from user relation.How can i fix this?

**Controller**

Method 1:

```
$post=Post::where('status',1)
 ->with([
'user' => function ($query) use ($request) {
$query->where('name',$request->name);
$query->select('name','age');
}
])
->latest();
```

Method 2 :

```
$p = Post::where('status', 1)
                ->with('user')
         ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->select('age', 'name');
                    }
                )
                ->get();
if ($request->name)
             {
                $p->user->where('name', $request->name); 
             }
```

Method 2 returns error `Exception: Property [user] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

**Post Model**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            'App\Models\User',
            'user_id',
            'id'
        );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel eager loading with where() from its relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741903/laravel-eager-loading-with-where-from-its-relation)

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh no. it  results the same I get with the above methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WhereHas` in your query like this :

```
$user_name=$request->name;
$p = Post::where('status', 1)
                ->with('user')
                ->WhereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_name) {
                    $query->where('user.name',$user_name);
                 })->get();
```

So you get the posts where the user of this post has the given name.

Comment: it gives the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `status` = 1 and exists (select * from `users` where `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `user.name` .....

Comment: It would likely be `users.name`, but that error is local to your database; adjust `->where('user.name', ...)` to `->where('users.name', ...)`, or whatever the actual table name is. Also, look into using `->withWhereHas()` to avoid having to type `->with('user')->whereHas('user', ...)`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence

Comment: As @TimLewis said , adjust it to your database table name.